# Is there some kind of a local DoS against processes?

Tags: denial-of-service, flooding, process

Is there an attack that somehow floods a target process (e.g. by repeatedly calling a WinAPI function that involves the process) and thereby crashes or temporarily disables it?

Comment: If I wanted to be snide, I could say that Chrome on a Mac is just such an attack ...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Denial-of-service_attack#Application-level_floods talks about what you ask

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Strictly speaking, what you are asking about is a [Fork Bomb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_bomb).

> ... wherein a process continually replicates itself to deplete
>   available system resources, causing resource starvation and slowing or
>   crashing the system.

In Windows (because you ask about that OS specifically) you cannot spawn new forks at the OS level, but you can create a cascade of new processes. That technique still falls under the "Fork Bomb" term.

Comment: So there is no targeted attack but only against system resources in general?

Comment: The fork bomb would simply slow down the whole system. I mean if there is something that only affects single processes.

Comment: Are you asking about a DoS that affects a particular process and nothing else? Sure, there are those, too. But those are usually caused by vulnerabilities in that process being unable to handle the requests - at some point, even a targeted attack will bring down the OS with the DoS.